# Mobile: Is it bad to implement a tab-like system that open different pages?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, tabs

In a mobile website (m.domain.com), as the page load time could be a number 1 problem, isn't this a bad way to implement?

edit: image deleted because of use of personal information.

Here "Profile, Claps, Highlights and Responses" tab-like links on Medium opens different pages (They are used as swipe tabs in mobile app version).

I think it's a better way to load the related content as nobody likes waiting or unless the content doesn't have an infinite scroll, that is limited content, then is it a good way to implement one page style links which is sticky?

Answer (score 1):

I think calling every horizontal navigation pane "Tab" is where the issue lies.

In mobile applications/websites, a normal navigation pane might have a look and feel of a tab navigation. Just because you can use the swipe feature, doesn't mean that all the content would be pre-loaded.

Allow the user to swipe but then show them the loading image/animation. Implement lazy loading so that each elements gets loaded in its own time.

[image: UX Stack Exchange navigation pane]

The above navigation pane is a great example. It might look like a tab navigation but it isn't